# Files from Local device to Streamlit Cloud

Tags: python, file, upload, cloud, streamlit

In my code I want to use a file from my directory and I put my absolut path as code, which doesn't work with Streamlit app. How can I change that?

My Github is https://github.com/sophiaia04/yolo.git and the main file is age_gender.py but the fil where I'm having issue with is: yolo_opencv.py

I tried file uploader but didn't really work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.